# How do I copy files to a Windows Share?

Tags: bash, samba

How do I use bash to copy files to a Windows share?

Comment: your question belongs to [su], voting to close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you're looking for a permanent setup (where `smbmount` might be better) you want to use the `smbclient` solution, which acts similar to a FTP client. You connect, then cd around and put/get files.

Connect as follows:

```
$ smbclient //computer.domain/sharename -U domain/username
Enter domain/username's password: 
Domain=[DN] OS=[Windows Server (R) 2008 Enterprise 6002 Service Pack 2] Server=[Windows Server (R) 2008 Enterprise 6.0]
smb: \>
```

Check the manual page here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/smbclient

Comment: Thanks for this, I am now able to connect to the remote windows computer. I can list the files and folders in that share. Now whats the command to copy a file located in my home folder to the windows share?

Comment: Just `put filename.txt` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is what worked for me. mkdir /mnt/smbshare and then sudo mount -t cifs //serverfs/c$ -o username=Jasonbe,password=password /mnt/smbshare

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you use *NIX.

So, basically, you have to mount the share with smbmount, then just use the cp command.

Refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smbmount) and [CIFS utils](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils)

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on @onur's point - as long as you have a filesystem mounted, (almost) all normal file utilities should be usable, as at that point it just appears to *nix as a filesystem.

Samba allows you to mount windows shares using smbmount, which comes as standard with many distro's and as an option with most others.

Commands such as cp, mv etc should work just fine.